# How to deal with large amounts of data in C++

Tags: c++, vector, bigdata, unordered-map

I have a large collection of data that is read in memory and used to do many computations with. I have many directories, where each one contains many txt files. 
For one directory, I read data from txt files and put the results in a vector (V) of vectors (of unsigned long long), where each vector corresponding to one file (reading files from the same directory is done in a parallel way). Each file contains about 1 million lines where each line contains about 15,000 unsigned long long elements. 
After this function, I create a an unordered_map, where the vector (V) containing all the previous vectors is added as keys to the map and if an element exists twice, his value is incremented. (We need to merge data from the same directory).
To store all data in memory, I create a vector of unordered_map, where each map contains elements coming from one directory.

```
   std::vector<std::unordered_map<unsigned long long, unsigned short> > vect_maps(nb_directories);
   for(i=0;i<nb_directories;i++){
      read_directory(direct[i],txt_files);
      size_t n_file = txt_files.size();
      size_t j;
      std::vector<std::vector<unsigned long long> > v(n_file);
      omp_set_dynamic(0)
      omp_set_num_threads(n_thread);
      #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(n_thread) shared(direct,txt_files)
           for(j=0;j<n_file;j++){
               std::string path=direct[i]+"/"+txt_files[j];
               One_file o(path, v[j]);
            }
       std::unordered_map<unsigned long long, unsigned short>::iterator it;
       vect_maps[i].clear();
       for(j=0;j<n_chunk;j++){
           size_t s=v[j].size();
           for(size_t p = 0;p<s;p++){
              it = vect_maps[i].find(v[j][p]);
              if (it != vect_maps.end()) {
                 it->second++;
               }
              else {
                  vect_maps[i][v[j][p]] = 1;
              }
           }
```

Till here, the algorithm takes a long time with a huge amount of memory.

After I need to create new keys from the existing ones in order to reduce the value (number of bits) of existing keys. New keys will be non sparse with smaller values.

```
    std::unordered_map<unsigned long long,std::vector<unsigned short> > all_maps;
    all_maps.clear();
    for (i = 0;i <nb_directories;i++) {
        for (auto it = vect_maps[i].begin(); it != vect_maps[i].end(); ++it) {
             if(all_maps.find(it->first) != all_maps.end())
                            all_maps[it->first][i] += 1;
                    else{
                            std::vector<unsigned short> value_vector= std::vector<unsigned short>(nb_directories,0);
                            value_vector[i]=1;
                            all_maps[it->first] = value_vector;
                    }
            }
    }
     std::unordered_map<unsigned long long, unsigned long long> map_link;
     for (auto it = all_maps.begin(); it != all_maps.end(); ++it){
            map_link[it->first] = i;
            i++;
     }
```

My question is that this way of implementation (vector + unordered_map) is the best, regarding time and memory consumption?

Comment: "Each file contains about 1 million lines where each line contains about 15,000 unsigned long long elements"   10^6 * 15 * 10^3 * 8 = 120*10^9 = 120GB  -  That's just the data in 1 file, not the mapping.  I think you need to revisit if you really need all that data in memory at once.   (For example, you could process it as you read it!)

Comment: I need all the data before processing it. I need to have a kind of matrix, where each row corresponds to one directory and normalize them.

Comment: "I need all the data before processing it" if you're so sure, then why ask?   There's (almost) always way to process data in chunks - and that's the whole thing of software engineering; finding problems and breaking them down to be smaller; so for example, you could process 300 lines at once; store your counts, and then do another round of processing.  This might take a little longer because you're doing several rounds, but now you don't need a super computer to be able to do it.

Comment: Which of the variables vect_maps, all_maps and map_link do you actually need? I believe @UKMonkey is right in suggesting you revisit how you process your input. Looking at the code you presented it should be possible to pass the variables you actually require to One_file constructor and populate it directly rather than via intermediate objects.

Comment: Each of the file in one directory represents a chunk. We chunked our data before processing it. Regarding the three variables: vect_maps, all_maps and map_link; I need to store values from each directory which represents a row in a matrix, this matrix is sparse so I used all_maps to access all values, and mat_link to shift the data (instead of having a sparse matrix with huge values). All these variables will be written to binary files to be processed after.

Comment: @Cecile ok, so one file = 1 row.  Great; this means you can jump around the entire matrix because if you know what row you're looking for you can work out which file to open; and if you know what column you know the offset to jump to  (assuming you've saved your data in binary format)  Now you have a way of not loading so much into memory.  If you're doing something to a particular row (say multiplying it) you might want to load just that row into memory, work on it, save the result and then clear out your cache.